# Sharing a lock via a python multiprocessing manager?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a `multiprocessing.Manager()` object to share a shareable lock in python 3.5:

```
import multiprocessing

mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
ns = mgr.Namespace()

ns.qlock = mgr.Lock()

print("Manager lock: ", ns.qlock)
```

Basically, I create a [`multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager), then using that manager, a synchronized namespace. I then use the same manager to create a serializeable lock, which as I understand how the manager works is actually a reference to a remote lock maintained by the manager worker process.

I then try to place the lock reference into the `mgr.Namespace()` instance. This succeeds.

Finally, when I try to *access* the lock via the namespace, everything fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("Manager lock: ", ns.qlock)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1016, in __getattr__
    return callmethod('__getattribute__', (key,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 732, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7f84c09c8aa8>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What really confuses me here is that **I can manually serialize the created lock proxy!**

```
import multiprocessing
import pickle

mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
ns = mgr.Namespace()

l = mgr.Lock()
print(pickle.dumps(l))
```

The above returns

```
b'\x80\x03cmultiprocessing.managers\nRebuildProxy\nq\x00(cmultiprocessing.managers\nAcquirerProxy\nq\x01cmultiprocessing.managers\nToken\nq\x02)\x81q\x03X\x04\x00\x00\x00Lockq\x04X$\x00\x00\x00/tmp/pymp-_hyy970i/listener-eroqlnwxq\x05X\x0c\x00\x00\x007f448c2b4aa8q\x06\x87q\x07bX\x06\x00\x00\x00pickleq\x08}q\ttq\nRq\x0b.'
```

so something is obviously going on in the namespace that is breaking the lock.

Of course, this suggests the option of manually serializing the lock before inserting it into the Namespace, but it'd be nice to not have to do that manually.

Why does this not work?

Comment: Why are you making your own `Namespace` object? A quick scan of the multiprocessing module suggests that these exist only to proxy actions from one process to another, i.e., you just get the `Lock` object from the `Manager` object and let it do any and all `Namespace` manipulation so that operations on the `Lock` happen in the correct process. Using a `Namespace` directly means that you must spell fields as `_foo` if they are remote and `foo` if they are local, i.e., you must begin tracking actual ownership, rather than letting the module do it for you.

Comment: @torek - I'm passing the namespace object (with a bunch of additional parameters) out into worker processes. The namespace is already being used to store my application's global state (exit flags, settings, etc...). I'd like to be able to distribute the lock via that mechanism as well.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, again just from a quick scan (I haven't used these particular features before) it looks as though you can't put these particular Locks in there because locks also do ownership tracking "under the hood" and the Namespace attempts to proxy references interfere with the Lock's own proxying. (If you were to put the Lock into some *other* object inside the Namespace object, it might work, though.)

Comment: @torek - I actually tried manually serializing the lock wrapper, passing that through the manager, and then manually unserializing, and that didn't work for some reference tracking reasons I don't understand. Anyways, I wound up ripping up and doing a bunch of restructuring to avoid the manager alltogether, but the question is still valid, I guess.

Comment: Yes, it's still valid enough. I think at this point the answer is "don't do that": you should not *have* to, as the Manager wraps everything in its own Lock so that you just use the fields and the Manager takes care of any locking required. You might *want* to, to break the locking into finer-grained locking, i.e., to not use the Manager's lock, but then you must also avoid the Namespace object as well.

Comment: Yeah. In this case, it was more "if x isn't initialized, do a bunch of setup for x(<val>) on-the-fly, as needed (including changing a bunch of other components in the manager)", but I just restructured to not use the manager alltogether.